# Get the count of files in a directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsfilemanager

How can I count the files in a directory? I couldn't find anything relevant in the class reference of `NSFileManager`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` returns an `NSArray`. Just send `count` to the array.

Answer (score 3):

`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:` returns an `NSArray` of **everything** in a directory (Files + Folders).

To get a count of files only, you can filter as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *files = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *itemsInFolder = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderpath error:NULL];

NSString *itemPath;
BOOL isDirectory;
for (NSString *item in itemsInFolder){
    itemPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", folderpath, item];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:item isDirectory:&isDirectory];
    if (!isDirectory) {
        [files addObject:item];
    }
}

return [files count];
```

Answer (score 0):

[subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath%3aerror%3a) returns an array with all path of target directory include sub-directory.

But as the document says,"you might not want to use it in performance-critical code."